# I just start programing and the following error does not stop appearing error CS1955 Non-invocable member 'Component.tag' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to search it in google but the answer doesn´t work´s in my specific situation and i don´t known nobody that know´s about programing, so i´m triying someone's with knowledge help me:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(collision.transform.tag("ground") = canJump = true)
    {
        canJump = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just started learning programming, I strongly suggest you to **not start with Unity**. Rather, learn the basics.

Comment: Equality comparison operator is `==`, not `=`

Comment: Do not give up your unity hopes but I would recommend you look up some c# syntax references.

Answer (score 2):

[Component.tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-tag.html) is a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), not a method, assuming that you are checking if the transform's tag is `ground`, and setting `canJump` to true if it is, you would write it like so:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(collision.transform.tag == "ground")
    {
        canJump = true;
    }
}
```

Note that to equate something you need to use the [==](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators) operator and not `=`, because `=` is only used when assigning a value to a variable.

As @derHugo mentioned you could also use [Component.CompareTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html)

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(collision.transform.CompareTag("ground"))
    {
        canJump = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In general you should rather use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) instead of `==` and I think that is where OP originally might have been confused ... it should probably have been `if(collision.transform.CompareTag("ground"))`